# How do I merge parent array and one child with different attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have comments and likes (acts_as_votable gem). I want to create one activity list and sort by `created_at` for comments and `updated_at` for votes.

```
@activity_list = (@user.comments + @user.find_up_voted_items)
```

`@user.find_up_voted_items` - it's not likes, but liked elements.

I can find `updated_at` time for vote using this code:

```
@post.votes_for.up.where(voter_id: @user.id).first.updated_at
```

How I can merge and sort it correctly?

Comment: Instead of `where(...).first` you can do `find_by(...)` with the same conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not necessarily performant as it builds an array instead of an ActiveRecord relation.

```
@ativity_list = (@user.comments + @user.votes.up).sort{|x,y| x.created_at <=> y.created_at}.map{|x| x.is_a?(Vote) ? x.votable : x}
```

`(@user.comments + @user.votes.up)` returns an array of comments and votes.

`#sort{|x,y| x.created_at <=> y.created_at}` uses an array sort on `created_at` field

`#map{|x| x.is_a?(Vote) ? x.votable : x}` changes the array from a comments / vote set to a comments / voted on set